# awk: line 1: syntax error at or near print how i could correct this command?

Tags: awk

this is my command but i dont know how I can execute without errors

```
         awk -v OFS='"' -v   FS='Name": "'      'for(i=1;i<=3;i++){{match($2, /5"/){print $0}}' sumacomando
```

Please help me

Answer (score -1):

I solve this

```
                  awk -v OFS='"' -v   FS='Name": "'      '{for(i=1;i<=3;i++) {match($2, /5"/)  ;{  print $0}}}' sumacomando
```